# Android dynamically add mapFragment, getView return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an trouble with map fragments in android.
I create fragment dynamically like this(replace frame layout).

```
mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.mapFragmentContainer, mapFragment, "mapFragment");
ft.commit();
```

and when i take view fragment returns null

```
fragment.getView();
```

So i need view for ground animation, so when I add animation to frameLayout map hides like api key isn't correct.